# Double dots when importing in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am watching this video tutorial and the person in the video says you have to use two dots because if you add the two dots it will be outside the folder I am importing it to. I don't understand why it has to be outside the folder I am importing it to.

Here is my line code where I imported:

```
import '../App.css';
```

Comment: .. two dots means your file App.css is located just outside folder current folder where you are doing import

Comment: if it is in same folder, simply use import './App.css';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file that you're importing the `App.css` file from isn't located in the same folder as the `App.css` folder. Specifically, it's located one level deeper inside another directory.

For example, if we had the following folder structure:

```
.
└── src/
    ├── components/
    │   ├── MyComponent.jsx
    │   └── App.css
    └── App.css
```

And let's say you want to write `import '../App.css` in the file `MyComponent.jsx`. If you write `import ./App.css`, you're importing the App.css that's right beside the `MyComponent.jsx` in the same folder. However, if you write `import '../App.css'`, you're instead importing the `App.css` that's under the `src/` folder.

You can check out this blog post I wrote for more information about JavaScript imports: https://dialect.so/blog/javascript-imports